# What does Unexpected token, expected ; mean in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need assisting working on Navigation Menu for mobile and table but getting an error message. What does this mean when you get an error message like this? How do I fix it if run into again

> Line 20:21:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

```
      this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
  19 | 
  20 |         toggleShow(){
     |                     ^
  21 |             this.setState({show: !this.state.show});
  22 |         }
```

**Full Code:**

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }

        this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);

        toggleShow(){
            this.setState({show: !this.state.show});
        }

        hide(e){
            if(e && e.relatedTarget){
              e.relatedTarget.click();
            }
        this.setState({show: false});
    }
```

**Full Code**

```
render() {
      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="FlexContainer NavbarContainer">

                  <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                      <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline">Kommonplaces</h2>
                      <div 
                      className="hamburger inlinev"  
                      onClick={this.toggleShow}  
                      onBlur={this.hide}>
                          <img alt="menubtn" src={hamburger}></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  {
                        this.state.show &&
                    ( 
                        <ul className="NavBar">
                            <Dropdown/>    
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to0="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Sign Up</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Login</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                  }
               </div>
         </Router>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Navigation;
```

Comment: You can only define functions like that (`toggleShow(){..}`) inside the class' body not inside its constructor.

Comment: @Titus What do you mean? Do you mean like ClassName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a javascript syntax error. Token is a character. Nothing to do with React.

You can check out these links about Js classes:
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-class-syntax-to-define-a-constructor-function

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-getters-and-setters-to-control-access-to-an-object

Your code should be like this for it not to produce an error:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }
    toggleShow() {
        this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this)
        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this)
        this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
    }

    hide(e) {
        if (e && e.relatedTarget) {
            e.relatedTarget.click();
        }
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the syntax for defining class functions inside the constructor. To fix this, use:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }

        this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShow(){
        this.setState({show: !this.state.show});
    }

    hide(e){
        if(e && e.relatedTarget){
            e.relatedTarget.click();
        }
        this.setState({show: false});
    }
}
```

In this example, the `constructor` ends before the definition of `toggleShow`.

Comment: So, you saying that I end the toggleShow without closing or calling it.

Comment: @bpdg No, I'm saying that you cannot define `toggleShow` using that syntax inside the `constructor` function, the way you've defined it can only be used inside the class body `class A { toggleShow() {..} }` not inside the constructor `class A { constructor(){ toggleShow(){..} } }`

Comment: @bpdg You can find mode details about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me and give me a resource to read